# What's that offset on the first 2-3 questions?

Tags: bug

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot, the vote counters of the first two questions is displayed with an offset with respect to the others.

I only noticed this yesterday and am not sure yet under what circumstances it appears. I think it is after clicking the "x new questions" button and seems to disappear after refreshing.